# How to serialize and parse protobuf 3 in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

The protobuf C++ guide is apparently for Protobuf2, because it explains that I should serialize with `bool SerializeToString(string* output)`, `bool ParseFromString(const string& data);`, [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#parsing-and-serialization), but I dont have any of them in my .h file:

```
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: uuid.proto

#ifndef GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_INCLUDED_uuid_2eproto
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_INCLUDED_uuid_2eproto

#include <limits>
#include <string>

#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
#if PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3013000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 3013000 < PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif

#include <google/protobuf/port_undef.inc>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arena.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arenastring.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
#include <google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h>
#include <google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h>
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>  // IWYU pragma: export
#include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>  // IWYU pragma: export
#include <google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h>
// @@protoc_insertion_point(includes)
#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
#define PROTOBUF_INTERNAL_EXPORT_uuid_2eproto
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN
namespace internal {
class AnyMetadata;
}  // namespace internal
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_CLOSE

// Internal implementation detail -- do not use these members.
struct TableStruct_uuid_2eproto {
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseTableField entries[]
    PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE(protodesc_cold);
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField aux[]
    PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE(protodesc_cold);
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseTable schema[1]
    PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE(protodesc_cold);
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::FieldMetadata field_metadata[];
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::SerializationTable serialization_table[];
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint32 offsets[];
};
extern const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::DescriptorTable descriptor_table_uuid_2eproto;
namespace message {
class UUID;
class UUIDDefaultTypeInternal;
extern UUIDDefaultTypeInternal _UUID_default_instance_;
}  // namespace message
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN
template<> ::message::UUID* Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<::message::UUID>(Arena*);
PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_CLOSE
namespace message {

// ===================================================================

class UUID PROTOBUF_FINAL :
    public ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Message /* @@protoc_insertion_point(class_definition:message.UUID) */ {
 public:
  inline UUID() : UUID(nullptr) {}
  virtual ~UUID();

  UUID(const UUID& from);
  UUID(UUID&& from) noexcept
    : UUID() {
    *this = ::std::move(from);
  }

  inline UUID& operator=(const UUID& from) {
    CopyFrom(from);
    return *this;
  }
  inline UUID& operator=(UUID&& from) noexcept {
    if (GetArena() == from.GetArena()) {
      if (this != &from) InternalSwap(&from);
    } else {
      CopyFrom(from);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Descriptor* descriptor() {
    return GetDescriptor();
  }
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Descriptor* GetDescriptor() {
    return GetMetadataStatic().descriptor;
  }
  static const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Reflection* GetReflection() {
    return GetMetadataStatic().reflection;
  }
  static const UUID& default_instance();

  static void InitAsDefaultInstance();  // FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY
  static inline const UUID* internal_default_instance() {
    return reinterpret_cast<const UUID*>(
               &_UUID_default_instance_);
  }
  static constexpr int kIndexInFileMessages =
    0;

  friend void swap(UUID& a, UUID& b) {
    a.Swap(&b);
  }
  inline void Swap(UUID* other) {
    if (other == this) return;
    if (GetArena() == other->GetArena()) {
      InternalSwap(other);
    } else {
      ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GenericSwap(this, other);
    }
  }
  void UnsafeArenaSwap(UUID* other) {
    if (other == this) return;
    GOOGLE_DCHECK(GetArena() == other->GetArena());
    InternalSwap(other);
  }

  // implements Message ----------------------------------------------

  inline UUID* New() const final {
    return CreateMaybeMessage<UUID>(nullptr);
  }

  UUID* New(::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Arena* arena) const final {
    return CreateMaybeMessage<UUID>(arena);
  }
  void CopyFrom(const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Message& from) final;
  void MergeFrom(const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Message& from) final;
  void CopyFrom(const UUID& from);
  void MergeFrom(const UUID& from);
  PROTOBUF_ATTRIBUTE_REINITIALIZES void Clear() final;
  bool IsInitialized() const final;

  size_t ByteSizeLong() const final;
  const char* _InternalParse(const char* ptr, ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseContext* ctx) final;
  ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint8* _InternalSerialize(
      ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint8* target, ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::io::EpsCopyOutputStream* stream) const final;
  int GetCachedSize() const final { return _cached_size_.Get(); }

  private:
  inline void SharedCtor();
  inline void SharedDtor();
  void SetCachedSize(int size) const final;
  void InternalSwap(UUID* other);
  friend class ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AnyMetadata;
  static ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::StringPiece FullMessageName() {
    return "message.UUID";
  }
  protected:
  explicit UUID(::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Arena* arena);
  private:
  static void ArenaDtor(void* object);
  inline void RegisterArenaDtor(::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Arena* arena);
  public:

  ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Metadata GetMetadata() const final;
  private:
  static ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Metadata GetMetadataStatic() {
    ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AssignDescriptors(&::descriptor_table_uuid_2eproto);
    return ::descriptor_table_uuid_2eproto.file_level_metadata[kIndexInFileMessages];
  }

  public:

  // nested types ----------------------------------------------------

  // accessors -------------------------------------------------------

  enum : int {
    kUuidFieldNumber = 1,
  };
  // string uuid = 1;
  void clear_uuid();
  const std::string& uuid() const;
  void set_uuid(const std::string& value);
  void set_uuid(std::string&& value);
  void set_uuid(const char* value);
  void set_uuid(const char* value, size_t size);
  std::string* mutable_uuid();
  std::string* release_uuid();
  void set_allocated_uuid(std::string* uuid);
  private:
  const std::string& _internal_uuid() const;
  void _internal_set_uuid(const std::string& value);
  std::string* _internal_mutable_uuid();
  public:

  // @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:message.UUID)
 private:
  class _Internal;

  template <typename T> friend class ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Arena::InternalHelper;
  typedef void InternalArenaConstructable_;
  typedef void DestructorSkippable_;
  ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ArenaStringPtr uuid_;
  mutable ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::CachedSize _cached_size_;
  friend struct ::TableStruct_uuid_2eproto;
};
// ===================================================================


// ===================================================================

#ifdef __GNUC__
  #pragma GCC diagnostic push
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-aliasing"
#endif  // __GNUC__
// UUID

// string uuid = 1;
inline void UUID::clear_uuid() {
  uuid_.ClearToEmpty(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), GetArena());
}
inline const std::string& UUID::uuid() const {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_get:message.UUID.uuid)
  return _internal_uuid();
}
inline void UUID::set_uuid(const std::string& value) {
  _internal_set_uuid(value);
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set:message.UUID.uuid)
}
inline std::string* UUID::mutable_uuid() {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_mutable:message.UUID.uuid)
  return _internal_mutable_uuid();
}
inline const std::string& UUID::_internal_uuid() const {
  return uuid_.Get();
}
inline void UUID::_internal_set_uuid(const std::string& value) {
  
  uuid_.Set(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), value, GetArena());
}
inline void UUID::set_uuid(std::string&& value) {
  
  uuid_.Set(
    &::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), ::std::move(value), GetArena());
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set_rvalue:message.UUID.uuid)
}
inline void UUID::set_uuid(const char* value) {
  GOOGLE_DCHECK(value != nullptr);
  
  uuid_.Set(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), ::std::string(value),
              GetArena());
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set_char:message.UUID.uuid)
}
inline void UUID::set_uuid(const char* value,
    size_t size) {
  
  uuid_.Set(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), ::std::string(
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(value), size), GetArena());
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set_pointer:message.UUID.uuid)
}
inline std::string* UUID::_internal_mutable_uuid() {
  
  return uuid_.Mutable(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), GetArena());
}
inline std::string* UUID::release_uuid() {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_release:message.UUID.uuid)
  return uuid_.Release(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), GetArena());
}
inline void UUID::set_allocated_uuid(std::string* uuid) {
  if (uuid != nullptr) {
    
  } else {
    
  }
  uuid_.SetAllocated(&::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited(), uuid,
      GetArena());
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set_allocated:message.UUID.uuid)
}

#ifdef __GNUC__
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif  // __GNUC__

// @@protoc_insertion_point(namespace_scope)

}  // namespace message

// @@protoc_insertion_point(global_scope)

#include <google/protobuf/port_undef.inc>
#endif  // GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_INCLUDED_GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_INCLUDED_uuid_2eproto
```

**uuid.proto:**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package message;

message UUID {
    string uuid = 1;
}
```

So, how to parse and serialize protobuf 3 in C++? I'd like to serialize to `uint8_t*` though. Apparently there are lots of ways but I don't see any of them!

Comment: The serialization methods aren't defined in the generated code.  They're inherited from the base `Message` class that your generated messages are derived from.  See the docs for [`MessageLite`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite) and [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message).